# Sorting selections alphabetically

Tags: php, html, sorting

I am wondering how to sort select options alphabetically. I was reading on another page where you can jQuery and I completely get the hang of it, I'm just confused a tad bit how I'd use it on the code I use for my selecting.

Here's my selection code:

```
<select class="form-control" id="rareImage" name="rareImage">
<?php
    if($open = opendir(ROOT .'/resources/images/small_furni')) {
        while(false != ($file = readdir($open))) {
            if($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
                continue;
            }
            echo '<option value="'. $file .'" '. ((isset($rareimage) && $rareimage == $file) ? 'selected' : '') .'>'. $file .'</option>';
        }
    }
?>
</select>
```

The other page suggested giving it a option value and then using jQuery to sort it. But like I said, I'm kind of confused how I'd go about using it on this code. Basically, the above code outputs a list of images to select from, but they're not in alphabetical order.

Reference I used: http://jsfiddle.net/3YjNR/2/

Comment: Why not just sort them with PHP?

Comment: You may want to use [`scandir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php), which sorts files automatically and is easier to use.

Comment: rvighne, thank you. I'll be looking into that as well. I'm taking other options to expand my knowledge on ways I can do this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i did, is that i put all the values i got from the while loop, into an array. I then sorted the array, and looped through it with a foreach... I think there is a better/faster way to do it, but this is what i got so far.

```
<select class="form-control" id="rareImage" name="rareImage">
<?php
$arr=array();
if($open = opendir(ROOT .'/resources/images/small_furni')) {
    while(false != ($file = readdir($open))) {
        if($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
            continue;
        }
        $files[]=$file;
    }
}
sort($files);
foreach($files as $file) echo '<option value="'. $file .'" '. ((isset($rareimage) && $rareimage == $file) ? 'selected' : '') .'>'. $file .'</option>';
?>
</select>
```

Comment: This worked. Very much appreciated and now I understand the concept. Thank you!